# Python 3 closing tkinter messagebox through code

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to Python and failing on first hurdle. I have a message box with a canvas with image loaded into it that's triggered to activate via a Passive infrared sensor.

Got everything working but I want the message box to disappear after 5 secs. The time delay isn't a problem but trying to get the message box to go is another thing been using `destroy()` but nothing.

Understand there are window levels I.e Toplevel. But wondered if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi @kevlar, could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

The small function below will do the job. By setting the type you can choose for: info, warning or error message box, the default is 'Info'. You can set also the timeout, the default is 2.5 seconds.

```py
def showMessage(message, type='info', timeout=2500):
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox as msgb

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    try:
        root.after(timeout, root.destroy)
        if type == 'info':
            msgb.showinfo('Info', message, master=root)
        elif type == 'warning':
            msgb.showwarning('Warning', message, master=root)
        elif type == 'error':
            msgb.showerror('Error', message, master=root)
    except:
        pass
```

Call the function as follow:
For message type 'Info' and timeout of 2.5 seconds:

```py
showMessage('Your message')
```

Or by your own settings for type message 'Error' and timeout 4 seconds:

```py
showMessage('Your message', type='error', timeout=4000)
```

Answer (score -1):

Without any code to go off of this is the best that I can give you.

This is an object-oriented program and truth be told I just started understanding what they are doing.

However just focus on `def create_window(self)`

It takes the window instance `t` which it declared and placed all the info on and `.destroy` it.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Create new window", command=self.create_window)
        self.button.pack(side="top")

    def create_window(self):
        self.counter += 1
        t = tk.Toplevel(self)
        t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
        l = tk.Label(t, text="This is window #%s" % self.counter)
        l.pack()
        b = tk.Button(t, text='close', command=t.destroy)
        b.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainWindow(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!